# How to use LINQ to compare values of sequential "neighbors" inside a List<>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, sequence

Take a look at this code:

```
        ColorResult contains Index, Color Name, and Probability

        Colors.Add(new ColorResult(1, "Unknown", 5f));
        Colors.Add(new ColorResult(2, "Blue", 80f));
        Colors.Add(new ColorResult(3, "Blue", 80f));
        Colors.Add(new ColorResult(4, "Green", 40f));
        Colors.Add(new ColorResult(5, "Blue", 80f));
        Colors.Add(new ColorResult(6, "Blue", 80f));
        Colors.Add(new ColorResult(7, "Red", 20f));
        Colors.Add(new ColorResult(8, "Blue", 80f));
        Colors.Add(new ColorResult(9, "Green", 5f));
```

Using LINQ, how would you accomplish the following:

1) Working sequentially, replace all items at the start of the List<> that have a Probability lower than 60 when the first TWO items that follow with a probability higher than 60 have the same value ("Unknown" becomes "Blue" because #2 and #3 are Blue and have Probability of 60+)

2) Replace any item with a probability lower than 60 that's surrounded with FOUR neighbors have the same value ("Green" becomes "Blue" because #2, #3, #5 and #6 are Blue and have Probability of 60+)

3) Working sequentially, replace any items at the end of the List<> that are preceded by TWO items with the same value (same as the first part, but in reverse).  In the sample data, nothing would happen to #9 since #7 would need to be "Blue" and would need 60+ Probability.

This is pretty easy with loops, but I am absolutely stumped on how to compare sequential "neighbors" in LINQ.

This was my original solution for part 1:

```
        bool partOneCompleted = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < Colors.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Colors[i].ResultConfidence > 60)
            {
                // This item does not need to be changed
                partOneCompleted = true;
            }
            if (!partOneCompleted)
            {
                int twoItemsAway = i + 2;
                if (twoItemsAway < Colors.Count)
                {
                    if (Colors[twoItemsAway].Name == Colors[twoItemsAway - 1].Name && Colors[twoItemsAway].ResultConfidence > 60 && Colors[twoItemsAway - 1].ResultConfidence > 60)
                    {
                        // The next item, and the one after that both have the same value and 60+ confidence
                        for (int loopBack = i; loopBack >= 0; loopBack--)
                        {
                            Colors[loopBack].Name = Colors[twoItemsAway].Name;
                        }

                        partOneCompleted = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Can any LINQ experts please share the most efficient implementation?

Comment: So you're asking people to write the code for you? If you done any attempts yourself, you should post them, so you look less lazy :p

Comment: At least share these "easy" loops, so people have a starting point.

Comment: I don't think there is any quick win with LINQ here. If the code is more readable and easy to understand with "regular loops" then I would say this is the way forward.

Comment: I'll post pseudo-code, but it doesn't use LINQ at all.  I bet there has to be an easier way than what I'm doing.

Comment: What's your motivation to switch to LINQ? Do you really just mean IEnumerables? You just need visibility of five elements to implement all of these rules, so you could write a method that reads in two elements ahead, remembers the previous two, computes your rules then yields the next element in the fixed sequence.

Comment: And isn't rule 2 redundant? Both 1 and 3 cover this. I assume 1 takes precedence if you had e.g. Blue 80, Blue 80, Green 40, Red 80, Red 80 - i.e. the Green becomes Red not Blue?

Comment: @Rup it seemed like a wise thing to use LINQ because I expected a short, concise solution.  Apparently loops are still a bit easier to understand.  To answer your question:  In your Blue, Blue, Green, Red, Red scenario, the result for Green would remain unchanged (not all 4 neighbors share the same value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with a test for part 1:

```
[Test]
public void Should_convert_leading_low_probability_colors()
{
    var colors = new List<ColorResult>
        {
            new ColorResult(1, "Unknown", 5f),
            new ColorResult(2, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(3, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(4, "Green", 40f),
            new ColorResult(5, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(6, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(7, "Red", 20f),
            new ColorResult(8, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(9, "Green", 5f)
        };

    ConvertLeadingLowProbabilityColors(colors);

    foreach (var colorResult in colors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(colorResult.Index + " " + colorResult.Color);
    }

    colors[0].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[1].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[2].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[3].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Green");
    colors[4].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[5].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[6].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Red");
    colors[7].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[8].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Green");
}
```

and implementation

```
private void ConvertLeadingLowProbabilityColors(IList<ColorResult> colors)
{
    var leadingBelow60 = Enumerable
        .Range(0, colors.Count)
        .TakeWhile(index => colors[index].Probability < 60)
        .ToList();
    if (leadingBelow60.Count > 0 && leadingBelow60.Count < colors.Count - 2)
    {
        int lastIndex = leadingBelow60.Last();
        var firstNext = colors[lastIndex + 1];
        var secondNext = colors[lastIndex + 2];
        if (firstNext.Probability > 60 &&
            secondNext.Probability > 60 &&
            firstNext.Color == secondNext.Color)
        {
            leadingBelow60.ForEach(index => colors[index].Color = firstNext.Color);
        }
    }
}
```

then added a test for part 3, since it is a variation of part 1:

```
[Test]
public void Should_convert_trailing_low_probability_colors()
{
    var colors = new List<ColorResult>
        {
            new ColorResult(1, "Unknown", 5f),
            new ColorResult(2, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(3, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(4, "Green", 40f),
            new ColorResult(5, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(6, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(7, "Red", 20f),
            new ColorResult(8, "Blue", 40f),
            new ColorResult(9, "Green", 5f)
        };

    ConvertTrailingLowProbabilityColors(colors);

    foreach (var colorResult in colors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(colorResult.Index + " " + colorResult.Color);
    }

    colors[0].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Unknown");
    colors[1].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[2].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[3].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Green");
    colors[4].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[5].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[6].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[7].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[8].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
}
```

and implementation:

```
private void ConvertTrailingLowProbabilityColors(IList<ColorResult> colors)
{
    var trailingBelow60 = Enumerable
        .Range(0, colors.Count)
        .Select(i => colors.Count - 1 - i)
        .TakeWhile(index => colors[index].Probability < 60)
        .ToList();
    if (trailingBelow60.Count > 0 && trailingBelow60.Count < colors.Count - 2)
    {
        int lastIndex = trailingBelow60.Last();
        var firstPrevious = colors[lastIndex - 1];
        var secondPrevious = colors[lastIndex - 2];
        if (firstPrevious.Probability > 60 &&
            secondPrevious.Probability > 60 &&
            firstPrevious.Color == secondPrevious.Color)
        {
            trailingBelow60.ForEach(index => colors[index].Color = firstPrevious.Color);
        }
    }
}
```

then, I tackled part 2. Again I started with a test:

```
[Test]
public void Should_convert_surrounded_low_probability_colors()
{
    var colors = new List<ColorResult>
        {
            new ColorResult(1, "Unknown", 5f),
            new ColorResult(2, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(3, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(4, "Green", 40f),
            new ColorResult(5, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(6, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(7, "Red", 20f),
            new ColorResult(8, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(9, "Green", 5f)
        };

    ConvertSurroundedLowProbabilityColors(colors);

    foreach (var colorResult in colors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(colorResult.Index + " " + colorResult.Color);
    }

    colors[0].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Unknown");
    colors[1].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[2].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[3].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[4].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[5].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[6].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Red");
    colors[7].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[8].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Green");
}
```

and this implementation:

```
private void ConvertSurroundedLowProbabilityColors(IList<ColorResult> colors)
{
    var surrounding4Modification = new Surrounding4ModificationStrategy();
    foreach (int index in Enumerable
        .Range(0, colors.Count)
        .Where(index => surrounding4Modification.IsMatch(colors, index)))
    {
        surrounding4Modification.Update(colors, index);
    }
}
```

This time it seemed cleaner to pull out a helper class:

```
public class Surrounding4ModificationStrategy
{
    public bool IsMatch(IList<ColorResult> input, int index)
    {
        if (index < 2)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (index >= input.Count - 2)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (input[index].Probability >= 60)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var secondPrevious = input[index - 2];
        if (secondPrevious.Probability < 60)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var firstPrevious = input[index - 1];
        if (firstPrevious.Probability < 60)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var firstNext = input[index + 1];
        if (firstNext.Probability < 60)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var secondNext = input[index + 2];
        if (secondNext.Probability < 60)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (new[] { secondPrevious.Color, firstPrevious.Color, firstNext.Color, secondNext.Color }.Distinct().Count() > 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void Update(IList<ColorResult> input, int index)
    {
        input[index].Color = input[index + 1].Color;
    }
}
```

Finally, I created a consolidated test with your data:

```
[Test]
public void Should_convert_all_low_probability_colors()
{
    var colors = new List<ColorResult>
        {
            new ColorResult(1, "Unknown", 5f),
            new ColorResult(2, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(3, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(4, "Green", 40f),
            new ColorResult(5, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(6, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(7, "Red", 20f),
            new ColorResult(8, "Blue", 80f),
            new ColorResult(9, "Green", 5f)
        };

    ConvertLowProbabilityColors(colors);

    foreach (var colorResult in colors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(colorResult.Index + " " + colorResult.Color);
    }

    colors[0].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[1].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[2].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[3].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[4].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[5].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[6].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Red");
    colors[7].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Blue");
    colors[8].Color.ShouldBeEqualTo("Green");
}
```

and an implementation that uses the methods created above:

```
public void ConvertLowProbabilityColors(IList<ColorResult> colors)
{
    ConvertLeadingLowProbabilityColors(colors);
    ConvertSurroundedLowProbabilityColors(colors);
    ConvertTrailingLowProbabilityColors(colors);
}
```

Were this my code base I would go on to add tests around edge cases like: all items having probability < 60 for parts 1 and 3; all but last ... for part 1; all but first for part 3; etc.

Comment: Thank you for your work, this is perfect, and a great example of why StackOverflow is so powerful.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of the first one, to get you going. The key is using `Enumerable.Range` so you have the index. As has been said, it'd be much more readable with loops.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class ColorResult
    {
        public int Index;
        public string Name;
        public float Prob;

        public ColorResult(int Index, string Name, float Prob)
        {
            this.Index = Index;
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Prob = Prob;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Index.ToString() + ", " + Name + ", " + Prob.ToString();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<ColorResult> Colors = new List<ColorResult>();

            Colors.Add(new ColorResult(1, "Unknown", 5f));
            Colors.Add(new ColorResult(2, "Blue", 80f));
            Colors.Add(new ColorResult(3, "Blue", 80f));
            Colors.Add(new ColorResult(4, "Green", 40f));
            Colors.Add(new ColorResult(5, "Blue", 80f));
            Colors.Add(new ColorResult(6, "Blue", 80f)); 
            Colors.Add(new ColorResult(7, "Red", 20f)); 
            Colors.Add(new ColorResult(8, "Blue", 80f));   
            Colors.Add(new ColorResult(9, "Green", 5f));


            var test1 = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, Colors.Count)
                        select (i < Colors.Count - 2 &&
                               (Colors[i].Prob < 60f) &&
                               (Colors[i + 1].Name == Colors[i + 2].Name) &&
                               (Colors[i+1].Prob > 60f) &&
                               (Colors[i+2].Prob > 60f)) ?
                        new ColorResult(1, Colors[i + 1].Name, Colors[i].Prob) :
                        Colors[i];


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good code, thank you.  One modification I would suggest:  It should stop once an item with Probability of 60+ is found.  In your current code, it replaces #4 as well.  In general, I'm starting to agree with you guys that loops may be better than LINQ for problems like these.

Comment: That would be very awkward to do and to read in LINQ (but possible using a subquery), for-loops would definately be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a yield-based solution, which isn't strictly LINQ I guess but it's LINQ-like. Implemented quickly; I'm sure there's better ways to do this. Apologies (and +1) to George for stealing his test framework.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  public class ColorResult
  {
    public int Index;
    public string Name;
    public float Prob;

    public ColorResult(int Index, string Name, float Prob)
    {
      this.Index = Index;
      this.Name = Name;
      this.Prob = Prob;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return Index.ToString() + ", " + Name + ", " + Prob.ToString();
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    // Iterate through the list remembering the last two elements
    // to implement rule 1
    public static IEnumerable<ColorResult> Rule1(IEnumerable<ColorResult> input)
    {
      ColorResult last2 = null;
      ColorResult last1 = null;
      foreach (var color in input)
      {
        if ((color.Prob < 60f)
            && (last1 != null) && (last1.Prob >= 60f)
            && (last2 != null) && (last2.Prob >= 60f)
            && (last2.Name == last1.Name))
        {
          color.Name = last2.Name;
        }
        yield return color;
        last2 = last1;
        last1 = color;
      }
    }

    // Iterate through the list with two element look-ahead
    // to implement rule 3
    public static IEnumerable<ColorResult> Rule3(IEnumerable<ColorResult> input)
    {
      ColorResult color = null;
      ColorResult ahead1 = null;
      foreach (var ahead2 in input)
      {
        if ((color != null) && (color.Prob < 60f)
            && (ahead1 != null) && (ahead1.Prob >= 60f)
            && (ahead2 != null) && (ahead2.Prob >= 60f)
            && (ahead1.Name == ahead2.Name))
        {
          color.Name = ahead1.Name;
        }
        yield return color;
        color = ahead1;
        ahead1 = ahead2;
      }
      // Using a null check here as a cheat way to test we've
      // actually had two inputs.
      // NB Will not preserve trailing nulls in the list;
      // you'll need to count inputs if you need that.
      if (color != null) yield return color;
      if (ahead1 != null) yield return ahead1;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
      List<ColorResult> Colors = new List<ColorResult>();

      Colors.Add(new ColorResult(1, "Unknown", 5f));
      Colors.Add(new ColorResult(2, "Blue", 80f));
      Colors.Add(new ColorResult(3, "Blue", 80f));
      Colors.Add(new ColorResult(4, "Green", 40f));
      Colors.Add(new ColorResult(5, "Blue", 80f));
      Colors.Add(new ColorResult(6, "Blue", 80f));
      Colors.Add(new ColorResult(7, "Red", 20f));
      Colors.Add(new ColorResult(8, "Blue", 80f));
      Colors.Add(new ColorResult(9, "Green", 5f));

      var processed = Rule3(Rule1(Colors));
      foreach (var color in processed)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(color);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe rules 1 and 3 are simply edge cases for rule 2. I would LINQify this starting with 2 extension methods:

1. a method that returns, for each element, it's surrounding neighbours. Add two null values at the beginning and the end to handle the edge cases. I called this method `WithSurroundingNeigbours`
2. a method that, from a list of 5 elements, returns whether the middle element should be excluded or not. I left this as an excercise :-)

Combined, this allows to write the resulting query like this:

```
       var results = from x in Colors.WithSurroundingNeighbours()
                     where !x.ItemShouldBeRemoved()
                     select x[2]; 



public static  class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<List<T>> WithSurroundingNeighbours<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input) where T : class
    {
        var q = new List<T>();
        var twoNulls = new T[] {null, null};
        foreach (var item in twoNulls.Concat(input).Concat(twoNulls))
        {
            q.Add(item);
            if (q.Count < 5) continue;
            yield return q;
            q.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }

    public static bool ItemShouldBeRemoved(this List<ColorResult> items) 
    {
        if (items.Count != 5) throw new ArgumentException("expected list with exactly 5 items");
        // TODO: return true when Item3 of the tuple should be removed
        // for the first item in the list, Item1 and Item2 are null
        // for the last item in the list, Item4 and Item5 are null
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution using loops, in case anyone is interested:

```
        bool startComplete = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < Colors.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Colors[i].ResultConfidence > 60)
            {
                // This item does not need to be changed
                startComplete = true;
            }
            if (!startComplete)
            {
                int twoItemsAway = i + 2;
                if (twoItemsAway < Colors.Count)
                {
                    if (Colors[twoItemsAway].Name == Colors[twoItemsAway - 1].Name && Colors[twoItemsAway].ResultConfidence > 60 && Colors[twoItemsAway - 1].ResultConfidence > 60)
                    {
                        // The next item, and the one after that both have the same value and 60+ confidence
                        for (int loopBack = i; loopBack >= 0; loopBack--)
                        {
                            Colors[loopBack].Name = Colors[twoItemsAway].Name;
                        }

                        startComplete = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        bool endComplete = false;
        for (int i = Colors.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (Colors[i].ResultConfidence > 60)
            {
                // This item does not need to be changed
                endComplete = true;
            }
            if (!endComplete)
            {
                int twoItemsAway = i - 2;
                if (twoItemsAway >= 0)
                {
                    if (Colors[twoItemsAway].Name == Colors[twoItemsAway + 1].Name && Colors[twoItemsAway].ResultConfidence > 60 && Colors[twoItemsAway + 1].ResultConfidence > 60)
                    {
                        // The next item, and the one after that both have the same value and 60+ confidence
                        for (int loopForward = twoItemsAway; loopForward < Colors.Count; loopForward++)
                        {
                            Colors[loopForward].Name = Colors[twoItemsAway].Name;
                        }

                        endComplete = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Fill in the middle values.

        for (int i = 2; i < Colors.Count - 2; i++)
        {
            if (Colors[i].ResultConfidence < 60)
            {
                int twoLeft = i - 2;
                int oneLeft = i - 1;
                int oneRight = i + 1;
                int twoRight = i + 2;

                if (Colors[twoLeft].Name == Colors[oneLeft].Name && Colors[oneLeft].Name == Colors[oneRight].Name && Colors[oneRight].Name == Colors[twoRight].Name
                    &&
                    Colors[twoLeft].ResultConfidence > 60 && Colors[oneLeft].ResultConfidence > 60 && Colors[oneRight].ResultConfidence > 60 && Colors[twoRight].ResultConfidence > 60)
                {
                    Colors[i].Name = Colors[oneRight].Name;
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq to operate on sequential items quite neatly:

```
  var colours = new List<string>(new[]{"red", "green", "blue"});
  var added = colours
              .Skip(1)
              .Zip(colours,
              (second, first) => first + second);
  foreach (var colour in added)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(colour);
  }
```

Notice that we skip the first element of the sequence, then zip the result with itself.
This gives:

> redgreen
>
> greenblue